# Create String for jQuery .css() Assignment

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign the following css to an element but it isn't assigning the css to the element.  Is this the best way to do this? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var col1 = "#616161";
var col2 = "#ffffff";
var cssStr = '"background": "linear-gradient(180deg, '+col+', '+col2+')", "background-clip": "text", "-webkit-text-fill-color": "transparent"';
console.log("CssStr: " + cssStr);
$(this).css({cssStr})
```

In Console Log:

```
CssStr: "background": "linear-gradient(180deg, #616161, #ffffff)", "background-clip": "text", "-webkit-text-fill-color": "transparent"
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/css/ - also, have you noticed that `col` is `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an object by putting the string representation of the properties inside `{}`. Just create the object directly, and substitute the variables into one of the property values. The easiest way to substitute variables is using a template literal instead of concatenation.

```
var css = {
    "background": `linear-gradient(180deg, ${col}, ${col2})`, 
    "background-clip": "text", 
    "-webkit-text-fill-color": "transparent"
};

$(this).css(css);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string to an object and pass an object to `.css()`. You cannot do the former and you should pass key-value pairs to the latter. I have commented out your second rule, because in this fiddle it prevented any graphics from manifesting:

```js
var col1 = "#616161";
var col2 = "#ffffff";
var cssStr = {
    "background": "linear-gradient(180deg, "+col1+", "+col2+")", 
    /*"background-clip": "text",*/
    "-webkit-text-fill-color": "transparent"
};
let context = $("#abc");
Object.keys(cssStr).map(item => context.css(item, cssStr[item]));
```

```css
#abc {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc"></div>
```